# jQuery .css('backgroundColor') issue

Tags: jquery, css, background, get

I've got a wee issue with my code. I've got a bunch of class elements with different background colors, named 'jq'. I animate the background color on hover and then revert it back to its original color: this is where .css('backgroundColor') should get the color of any given div that is hovered and with jq class. 
Instead, I get the div background reverted to white. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
            $(".jq").hover( 
            var bgcol = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
                function(){ 
                  $(this).animate({     
                     backgroundColor: "#EAEAEA",
                     color:"#333"
                  },trans);
                },
                function() {      
                  $(this).animate({
                    backgroundColor:'bgcol',
                     color:"#888"
                  },trans);
                });         
            });
```

Comment: did you try: background-color
your text is a bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntactical errors here

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".jq").hover( 
        function(){ 
            var bgcol = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
            $(this).animate({     
                backgroundColor: "#EAEAEA",
                color:"#333"
            }, trans).data('hoverbackground', bgcol);
        },
        function() {      
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: $(this).data('hoverbackground'),
                //backgroundColor: "#EFEFEF",
                color:"#888"
            }, trans).removeData('hoverbackground');
        });         
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RLbs4/)